# Why doesn't this code work for a[100] and above? (project euler 2 in C)

Tags: c

Here is my code:

I don't understand why it gives me the wrong answer above 50.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int i, sum=0;
    long long int a[50];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;
   for(i=2;i<50;i++)
   {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
        if(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]<4000000) 
        sum = sum + a[i];
   }
printf("%lld", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe because loop works till 50 only...

Comment: Can you mention desired output?

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work. Just the code that does work isn't useful. Also, please copy-paste the problem description in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *first* mistake was not breaking out of the loop when a term
exceeded 4,000,000. You don’t need to consider terms beyond that for the
stated problem; you don’t need to deal with integer overflow if you stop
there; and you don’t need anywhere near 50 terms to get that far.

Nor, for that matter, do you need to store all of the terms, unless you
want to look at them to check correctness (and simply printing them
would work just as well for that).

Answer (score 2):

You have an integer overflow. Fibonacci numbers get really big. Around `F(94)` things get out of the range of 64 bit integers (like `long long`).

```
F(90) = 2880067194370816120   >= 2^61
F(91) = 4660046610375530309   >= 2^62
F(92) = 7540113804746346429   >= 2^62
F(93) = 12200160415121876738  >= 2^63
F(94) = 19740274219868223167  >= 2^64
F(95) = 31940434634990099905  >= 2^64
F(96) = 51680708854858323072  >= 2^65
```

When the overflow happens, you will get smaller, or even negative numbers in `a` instead of the real fibonacci numbers. You need to workaround this overflow.